# Draggable UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have 4 UIViews inside of a main view controller view. All I need to be able to do is drag the views around the "screen". Is UIScrollView the best option for this, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIScrollView should be used for scrolling, not dragging. And the 4 scroll views won't work if they're overlapped so don't even think of using UIScrollView in your case.

A dedicate UIView subclass that overrides `-touches*****:withEvent:` is needed. See http://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C08-Gestures/01-Direct%20Manipulation/ for example.

Answer (score 5):

Apple's [Touches](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Touches/index.html) sample application contains code that does just this, so you might want to check it out.